# VBA: Multiplication using the value from a Inputbox

Tags: vba, excel

Do we have any solution to get this code working,

```
 Sub FindSum()
    Dim Euro1 As String
    Euro1 = InputBox("", "")
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*" & Euro1.Value
End Sub
```

Expected:
This code will select the value from a field and multiply it with the value provided in Inputbox.

Comment: Remove the `.Value` part.

Comment: Thanks @braX   That worked, I am really silly, haven't thought about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub FindSum()
    Dim Euro1 As String
    Euro1 = InputBox("", "")
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*" & Euro1
End Sub
```

Try :)

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> Dim Euro1 As String
> ```

You're declaring `Euro1` as a `String`. Strings are a primitive type in VBA, and primitive types don't have members you can call, which means this:

```
Debug.Print Euro1.Value
```

Is illegal.

If you have a `String`, you can simply use it as such:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*" & Euro1
```

This will definitely cause other issues though: you need to read up on **user input validation**. Code that systematically treats user input as valid is always going to have problems. Here we're looking at Excel being unable to compute the value of `=RC[-1]*Hi There I'm some invalid input`.

Consider using the `IsNumeric` built-in function to determine if a string contains a value that can be treated as a number, if you mean to use a string as a number.

```
If IsNumeric(Euro1) Then
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*" & Euro1
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid input!"
End If
```